# Can't create AccordionItem template for Accordion from WPF Toolkit

Tags: wpf, xaml, .net-4.0, wpftoolkit, app.xaml

I'm using the WPF Toolkit for a project that I need an Accordion control. The control initially works fine (there is a known design bug but otherwise no problem), but anyone who tried the control knows that weird blue background that comes with it. I want to change the default background for the control and I go to Expression Blend, right click an AccordionItem instance, and go to Edit Template -> Edit a Copy. I select to apply it all app-wise, and it creates a new template (which should be identical to the original). The control looks exactly the same, but anything inside an AccordionItem gets invisible. No errors, no warnings. They just get invisible. When I click their tag in XAML, I can see they are selected, just as if they are behind something, but they aren't! When I delete the (never-touched) control template from the App.xaml, it gets back to normal, but I'm back again with the blue background. Here is the untouched XAML template created by Blend:

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type System_Windows_Controls:AccordionItem}">
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFECECEC"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type System_Windows_Controls:AccordionItem}">
                    <Grid Background="Blue" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}">
                        <Border x:Name="Background" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="1" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition x:Name="cd0" Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition x:Name="cd1" Width="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition x:Name="rd0" Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition x:Name="rd1" Height="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <System_Windows_Controls_Primitives:AccordionButton x:Name="ExpanderButton" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" FontStyle="{TemplateBinding FontStyle}" FontStretch="{TemplateBinding FontStretch}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsTabStop="True" IsChecked="{TemplateBinding IsSelected}" Margin="0" Padding="0" Grid.Row="0" Style="{TemplateBinding AccordionButtonStyle}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                <System_Windows_Controls_Primitives:ExpandableContentControl x:Name="ExpandSite" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" FontStyle="{TemplateBinding FontStyle}" FontStretch="{TemplateBinding FontStretch}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsTabStop="False" Margin="0" Percentage="0" RevealMode="{TemplateBinding ExpandDirection}" Grid.Row="1" Style="{TemplateBinding ExpandableContentControlStyle}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                                    <System_Windows_Controls_Primitives:ExpandableContentControl.Clip>
                                        <RectangleGeometry/>
                                    </System_Windows_Controls_Primitives:ExpandableContentControl.Clip>
                                </System_Windows_Controls_Primitives:ExpandableContentControl>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Am I missing something? I am not super used to templates and styles, but anything from "Edit a copy", in an untouched state, should act identical to the default template, but it doesn't. I can safely delete the setters other than the Template, and it won't change. There is something with the Template setter, which makes the AccordionItem act abnormally.

Answer (score 2):

You just delete string `Background="Blue"` this property is of the `Grid` which is first child of `Control Template`.